# Which Hostile Mob will  spawn in a dark room?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In a dark room with the requirements met to be able for hostile mobs to spawn, is the spawning of different types of hostile mobs (etc, Creeper, Skeleton, Spider, Enderman, Zombie) random or is there a preference for a specific hostile mob to spawn?

Comment: Can't it be both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the correct spawn conditions are present, all passive mobs have the same chance to spawn, and the 4 basic aggressive mobs (spider, skeleton, zombie and creeper) have an equal chance to spawn. Mobs that spawn more rarely are: Endermen, Wolves and (while not really having a chance, to spawn, they still are encountered more rarely) Silverfish.

The rarest of all mobs is the Spider Jockey, which is a Skeleton riding a Spider, every time a spider spawns, there is a 1% chance it will spawn as a Spider Jockey.

Comment: Passive mobs won't spawn in dark, Endermen won't spawn if the ceiling is 2 blocks, and silverfish only spawn in strongholds(after breaking a block). -Clarification of correct spawn conditions, especially since I will assume he's making a grinder. :)

Comment: Are wolves considered hostile mobs that spawn under hostile mob conditions?  I thought they spawned exclusively during the day and only attacked if you attacked their pack.

Comment: Possibly update adding that Witches spawn about the same percentage as Endermen? Rare spawns also now include Baby Zombies and Chicken Jockeys.
Above comment is correct, as well.